# ExtJS toggle many elements?

Tags: jquery, extjs

I'm used to jQuery where I would do `$('pre').toggle()`. What's the most straighforward ExtJS equivalent of this? I'm using version 4.1.1.1.

I'm lost switching between `Ext.fly` and `Ext.dom.Query.select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ext.select](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext-method-select)(selector, [unique], [root]).
For example:

```
Ext.select('pre').toggle();
```

More examples:

```
 Ext.select ('div: first'); // select a first div
 Ext.select ('div: last'); // select a last div
 Ext.select ('div: even'); // fetch even div
 Ext.select ('div: odd'); // fetch the odd div containing the 'bar'
 Ext.select ('input: checked]'); // select all input c checked = true
 Ext.select ('div {display = none}'); // select all the div with CSS-style display = none
 Ext.select ('div {display! = None}'); // select all the div with CSS-style display! = None
 Ext.select ('div {height% = 2}') // select all the div with CSS-style in which the height is divided into two
 Ext.select ('div: not (form)') // fetch div, not containing a form
 Ext.select ('div: has (a)') // fetch div, containing a link
 Ext.select ('input: checked') // select all checked checkboxes
```

Selectors in Sencha docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query

The Ext.fly() method is similar to Ext.get(), with the difference that it is optimized for garbage collection. The developers recommend using it in cases where there is no need to reuse the resulting DOM element.